# Rails Assets failing to precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, solidus

Hi everyoneI’m having an issue precompiling the stylesheets of my rails 5.2.0 e-commerce with Solidus.  Whenever I serve I get the following message:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Undefined variable: "$color-6".):
>
> app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/_bootstrap_custom.scss:16>

`$color-6` is defined on the file variables.scss which is imported previously on the application file;

Anyway, if I manually solve this specific problem, there is always a next variable that is undefined.

Also, I found out that if I remove the stylesheet folder, I refresh, then I restore it and I refresh again, the page works perfectly and all the variables are identified.

That’s the way I have been working locally, but obviously, I can’t deploy now.

When I run `rake assets:precompile` I have the exact same issue.

Does anyone have a clue of what it might be?

Comment: When you say the variables are being imported previously on the application file. Are you referring to `<link/>` imported? Or are the variables.scss `@import` inside the `_bootstrap_custom.scss`?

Comment: All the .scss files are @imported from the same file.